# Batch - pushd, cd and more with hardcore special characters like: `´~`}][{^!§$%&()=+-~ possible?

Tags: batch, batch-file, path, encoding

Is something like

```
cd c:\test\`\´\}\]\[\{\³\²\^\°\!\§\$\%\&\(\)\=\+\-\~\
```

possible at all?

I also have a horrible foldername like:

```
°!§$%&()=`´}][{³²^@€~#'_-.,;
```

Honestly, this is very extreme and a rather unlikely situation, but is it possible to navigate through such paths like?

```
cd C:\Users\username\downloads\weird_mp3_files\°!§$%&()=`´}][{³²^@€~#'_-.,;\
```

To state the obvious. I just tested the commands and as expected it failed.

Comment: What problems are you actually trying to solve? What are you trying to accomplish with these commands?

Comment: The goal is, to add this to my music conversion script. I noticed, many files are ignored, because they contain special characters like these. These lines are just the absolute worst possible situation. But music often contains something like money$.mp3, `rapgod´.mp3, 5€, 50%, q&a (this one is solveable with quotes), and lovesong!.mp3... Many of these characters are in my music collection and would require manual renaming. I already found out, that some characters are not problematic. But some are definitely. But yet windows allows such filenames on the standard API.

Comment: I do not even care, if the signs are kept. I rather would just wipe them off, but that likely does not work without first being able to open them in a script in the first place.

Comment: **PowerShell** can handle thses names much easier with the `-LiteralPath` parameter option available to most cmdlets.

Comment: This would be a nice idea. I mean, I will not rewrite the batch script I have, but I can just start a powershell script to remove all the special characters from the files and paths as one of the first commands and than run the rest of the code. This would work. But I now have to digg into another language. sigh... But thanks for the tip. I honestly doubt, that there is a solution for batch. It fails escaping many of the characters above (1/3 of the characters are not working in a test). And I cannot see a hex or binary workaround. Let's get started (well tomorrow).

Comment: Copy this to a **PowerShell** prompt: `'money$.mp3, ``rapgod´.mp3, 5€.mp3, 50%.mp3, q&a.mp3 , lovesong!.mp3'.Split(',') | %{ $_.Trim() -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9\.]', '_' `. You could add characters to the "not whitelist" string.